# Notes gone after upgrade to iOS 10.0.2

Tags: ios

I have just updated my iPad Air to 10.0.2 and now cannot find any Notes. I have checked iCloud and there is nothing there. Irrespective of whether a backup was made, upgrading should not remove user entered data, so why has this version upgrade removed all my notes?

Comment: To answer your explicit question: There might have a been a glitch or a bug or iCloud might have burped. I don't think anyone can tell you why they are gone. (Well, maybe somebody at Apple who has access to server logs, but ...) This is why you make a backup - to protect against an error occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I also lost various notes. I went to settings, iCloud and my notes were not turned on for iCloud backup storage. I turned it on, and voila, my notes were back on "my iPad"

Answer (score 0):

Certain notes of mine disappeared also. So, I restored an iCloud backup from 4 days ago, when I still had all of my notes, and they're still missing. I think what's causing it is the new little intro screen you see the first time you click on notes. After you click ok or advance or whatever, you go to the screen "Gmail" or "cloud" where you pick which notes you want to look at. Gmail has my notes, and sadly many or missing. 
What's odd is that somehow while accessing notes a week ago (before I installed IOS10), I got kicked into the screen "Gmail or cloud". I chose Gmail, and found a select few notes were missing. So I restored from a backup and all of my notes were there again.
Now, after updating, I have the exact same problem, but this time, restore from iCloud didn't fix the problem. I wish it'd just let me go directly to the notes on my phone without making me choose the source like before. My gut tells me that's what's causing the issue.